# Automated Process User - Create Event - Insufficient Acess

Tags: process-builder, automation

I'm trying to create an Event via automation, but I keep getting the following error: "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY." Our process is below

1. A scheduled flow triggers a subflow
2. The subflow creates a custom object
3. Process Builder sees the custom object is created and calls a flow
4. This flow attempts to create an Event

The problem seems to be that (a) Scheduled flows are run by user "Automated Process" and then (b) user Automated Process doesn't have sufficient rights to create an Event.

Interestingly, if we remove step (1), then everything works. This appears to be because in that scenario the user is not Automated Process. We need to use scheduled flows, however, so this isn't a workaround.

Any advice on what to do here? Can we modify the permissions of Automated Process so that it can create an Event? Can we set the User running a flow within the flow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to grant Automated Process user access to the scheduled flow. This can be done by coercing the URL (hat tip to @mattandneil)

Step 1 - get profile for Automated Process User (use Developer Console)

```
select id, name, profileid from user where name = 'Automated Process'
```

Step 2 - insert the profileId from step1 into the URL that permissions the Flow to a profile:

```
https://xxx.salesforce.com/_ui/system/user/ProfileFlowPermissionEdit/e?profile_id=theAutomatedProcessUserProfileId
```

The alternative way is to manually insert a `PermissionSetAssignment` record. You can see a version of this (albeit for invocable apex classes which also must be permissioned) in [this Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003aTkQAI) *(vote up)*

Comment: Given that the "manual insert of a permission set assignment" for the automated process using Apex was recommended (according to the comment in the idea) by Salesforce themselves, I'd put that as the primary solution and the "URL hack" (which isn't really a hack, I suggest) as the secondary solution. Great to know though, so thanks.

Comment: Really appreciate the help. I'm fairly new to working with Salesforce, and have a few follow up questions if you've got a moment:
- I've got the Id for Automated Process
- The URL above in Step 2 works, however, there's no flows available. How do I make flows available to move over?
- Alternatively, I read how to assign a permission set to automated process. Will assigning a permission set limit Automated Process, however? I'm worried I won't provision everything, and an error will occur

Comment: @treesgoblue each PSA is a junction between a permissionable item and a user so you won't mess anything up